# Right aligning SelectBoxIt controls in a horizontal form

Tags: css, asp.net, html, twitter-bootstrap

I would like how to right-align the control labels next to the SelectBoxIt dropdownlists in correspondence with the **"Process Date From" label** which would push the SelectBoxIt controls over accordingly.

The "Process Date From" label is in column 1 as is the control labels next to the SelectBoxIt dropdownlists but they are not right aligned like the "Process Date From" label.

I've tried several bootstrap classes, but can't get it tow work....

Here is my code, and below that is the image:

### HTML

Position:
                                                                
                                                                    Warranty Manager
                                                                    Warranty Admin
                                                                
                                                            
                                                            MFR Code/Dsc:
                                                            
                                                                
                                                            
                                                        
                                                        
                                                            
                                                                User:
                                                                
                                                                    Select All
                                                                    JM_WhyManager_1
                                                                
                                                            
                                                            
                                                                Sent Proc Status:
                                                                
                                                                    Select All
                                                                    Successfully Sent
                                                                    Unsuccessfully Sent
                                                                
                                                            
                                                        
                                                        
                                                            Process Date From:
                                                            
                                                            To:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After further insight, I got away from the traditional grid-system layout for horizontal forms to my own dismay...

I corrected this by adding the "col-sm-2" class on the label control for the select box and took it away from the outside div which contained the label & selectbox controls.

I also wrapped the selectboxit control in a div and put the "col-sm-2" class on it.

All of the above corrected the error.

Below is my code and below that is the updated screen shot.

### HTML

```
<div class="container nopadding">
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <div class="control-group">
                                                            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="ddlAppealTransmissionLogPosition">Position:</label>
                                                            <div class="col-sm-2">
                                                                <select id="ddlAppealTransmissionLogPosition" class="form-control">
                                                                    <option value="Warranty Manager" selected>Warranty Manager</option>
                                                                    <option value="Warranty Admin">Warranty Admin</option>
                                                                </select>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="txtAppealTransmissionLogPositionManufacturerCode">MFR Code/Dsc:</label>
                                                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtAppealTransmissionLogPositionManufacturerCode" placeholder="Enter Manufacturer">
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <div class="control-group">
                                                            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="ddlAppealTransmissionLogUser">User:</label>
                                                            <div class="col-sm-2">
                                                                <select id="ddlAppealTransmissionLogUser">
                                                                    <option value="Select All" selected>Select All</option>
                                                                    <option value="JM_WhyManager_1">JM_WhyManager_1</option>
                                                                </select>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="control-group">
                                                            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="ddlAppealTransmissionLogSentProcessStatus">Sent Proc Status:</label>
                                                            <div class="col-sm-2">
                                                                <select id="ddlAppealTransmissionLogSentProcessStatus">
                                                                    <option value="Select All" selected>Select All</option>
                                                                    <option value="Successfully Sent">Successfully Sent</option>
                                                                    <option value="Unsuccessfully Sent">Unsuccessfully Sent</option>
                                                                </select>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="dteAppealTransmissionLogRequestedFromDate">Process Date From:</label>
                                                        <input class="col-sm-2" id="dteAppealTransmissionLogRequestedFromDate" placeholder="From Date" type="text" />
                                                        <span class="label label-default">To:</span>
                                                        <input class="" id="dteAppealTransmissionLogRequestedToDate" placeholder="To Date" type="text" />
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
```

[image]